# I get the error qsub: Bad UID for job execution when trying to submit a job via PBS

Tags: centos, queue, torque, pbs

OS Version:
CentOS release 4.6 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m
2.6.9-100.ELsmp

When I attempt to run a job it gives me the error as follows.

```
qsub: Bad UID for job execution
```

I have created a fresh user account and the same error occurs, yet other users on the same machine can run jobs without a problem.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instructions here: http://www.bo.infn.it/alice/introgrd/pbsabout/node18.html suggest that you are running it as wrong user.

> ```
> Invalid user in #PBS -u new-user
>
> $ qsub sube.cmd
> qsub: Bad UID for job execution
> ```
>
> The user name defined in the user list is either undefined or
>   different from the user name of the job submitter or the user UID and
>   GID at the executing node are different from the ones in the
>   submitting node. In this case, first of all check that the #PBS -u
>   directive specifies a valid user, then check that user IDs are the
>   same:
>
> $ id `whoami` uid=501(myusrname) gid=501(myusrname)
>   groups=501(myusrname) $ grep -e "PBS -u" cpbs.cmd
>
> PBS -u alice001 $ id alice001 uid=10417(alice001) gid=1395(alice) groups=1395(alice)
>
> and change the #PBS -u as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the host the */etc/hosts.equiv* fixed my issue.
But I had already added these lines to `qmgr`.

```
set server operators += username@servername.local
set server acl_users += username
set server managers += username@servername.local
set server acl_hosts += servername.local
set server operators += username@servername.local
```

Then I did a `/etc/init.d/pbs_server restart`.

You can restart the *pbs_server* even if you are already running.
You don't have to add the server to */etc/hosts.equiv* if you are submitting jobs on the server that is running the *pbs_server*.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old, but I recently ran into this issue and I performed the following steps:

- Ensure the UID and GID matches across the cluster for the user in question
- `qmgr -c "set server flatuid=true"`
- `qmgr -c "set server acl_roots+=username@*"`
- `qmgr -c "set server operators+=username@*"`

Here * is a wildcard for all hosts. Works like a charm!  Probably not super secure but definitely works!

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I received this error when trying to submit a job while working in an interactive job. Exiting the interactive qsub and submitting from the head node worked.

Answer (score -1):

two procedures:

1. add ""+::::::"" at the end of the /etc/passwd file
2. make sure the node where users submit jobs have all other nodes well defined in file /etc/hosts.equiv

reference:
search Bad UID for job execution in torque admin guide pdf.